# woocommerce find author or vendor by product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins, dokan

I went to check if product belong to current vender to show edit and remove button Is there function as an example : product->get_vendor()
[image]
thx ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get vendor like this:

```
$vendor_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', get_the_id() ); //or $product->get_id()
$vendor = new WP_User($vendor_id);
```